# Delay reading of address a specific amount of time

Tags: assembly, mips32

Good day! I have an inquiry:

I want to implement a function that gets the number of milliseconds since a processor has started; such data is accessible to me through a certain address. However, I want to read this address after a specific amount of time has passed. Such amount is a function parameter. How could I implement such delay in assembly?

Comment: One question per question please. See [ask].

Comment: Read it immediately, add the wanted delay to that value, and keep that value for comparison. Then keep reading the value at certain address until it will reach the calculated one, then return. If you can't read that value meanwhile, you must calculate the delay by some other timing mechanism (depends on your target platform, what is available, if anything).

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you; your suggestion truly helped me out.